# Reason of not marking Exception as abstract

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Microsoft's [Best Practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions#use-the-predefined-net-exception-types) says:

> Introduce a new exception class only when a predefined one doesn't apply.

And:

> When a custom exception is necessary, name it appropriately and derive it from the Exception class.

Deriving from the Exception class makes sense because that makes it possible for us to handle specific exceptions and (for example) log and throw the rest:

```
try
{
    //something that might throw exceptions
}
catch(InvalidOperationException)
{
    //Do something
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Log and throw other exception
    throw;
}
```

I cant think of a reason why one would want to create an instances of the Exception base class. So **why is Exception not marked as an abstract class?**

I thought catching an abstract Exception might cause some *special* behaviour, but that does not seem to be the case:

```
public abstract class AbstractException : Exception
{

}

public class MyException : AbstractException
{

}

//...

try
{
   throw new MyException();
}
catch (AbstractException)
{
   //Works fine
}
```

Comment: Although the guidance is to always subclass Exception, it's not uncommon to throw it directly, especially e.g. for cases that *should* never happen. Bear in mind that the abstract-ness of `Exception` will have been defined by the very first version of .NET, but the guidelines will have been written after that.

Comment: @canton7 The fact that an Exception is thrown means for me that it is an definded event and therefore should use a suitable implementation of the Exception class. But this probably opinion based. But your comment regarding the .Net Version and guidlines makes sense to me, thanks.

Comment: I completely agree, but other people don't, and you will see a lot of `throw new Exception("...")` in other peoples' code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstract classes are only *required* when there are abstract members. `Exception` doesn't have those so it doesn't *require* to be abstract.

But Microsoft *could* make it abstract to comply to their own best practices. Well, best practices are not set in stone, so a developer should have the choice to deviate from them. The non-abstract `Exception` provides that possibility.

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of cases when you don't need any special or additional information to "describe" an exceptional situation in a computation flow. The `Exception` type is very suitable for such situations so that you don't have to define a new types for the generic exceptional situations. Being an abstract type the `Exception` wouldn't allow you to instantiate it and you'll have to invent some generic exception types from project to project in order to have an exception type "understandable" by all high-level consumers (that is provide a way to all consumers to catch and handle all exceptions regardless of an exception type specialization).

Comment: One can always use the Exception class to catch any exception (like my last code sample). As an 'high-level consumer' i would prever new types of exceptions. Just to be able to catch specific cases.

Comment: @Hyarus You never know who is your high-level consumer - you prefer specific exceptions but one can develop a component used by another external components (i.e. a library used in other projects) and it's better to impose less-restricted standards in order to give more options for your consumers to choose: bother of specific exception types or just handle generic exceptions. The `Excpetion` gives you this possibility but doesn't take away the possibility to follow specific exceptions schema.